# How to make a search bar which search a particular field in a website using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to make a search bar with select tag. If someone will click on any of the options like Bus driver then in the comment box the field with same text will come. I am using JavaScript, PHP with HTML and CSS. I am trying but its not working. I have index.php and a database with two tables.**You can also give me the codes of an example.**

My javascript code for search bar:-

```js
<script>
        const searchFun = () => {
            let select = document.getElementById('select_job');
            var x = select.val();
            let field = <?= $row['field'] ?>
            var y = field.val();

            if (x == y) {
                document.getElementById("mainContainer").innerHTML = "";
            } else {
                alert("Sorry no Jobs found")
            }
        }
    </script>
```

My search bar code:-

```
<select id="select_job" class="label-field form-control" onkeyup="searchFun()" name="field">
    <option value="">Choose your field...</option>
    <option>Accountants</option>
    <option>Aerospace Engineers</option>
    <option> Biologist</option>
    <option> Black Belt</option>
    <option> Blender</option>
    <option> Bookkeeper</option>
    <option> Bookseller</option>
    <option> Branch Manager</option>
    <option> Brand Ambassador</option>
    <option> Brand Manager</option>
    <option> Budget Analyst</option>
    <option> Bus Driver</option>
    <option> Business Analyst</option>
    <option>Computer User Support Specialists</option>
    <option>Computer Systems Analysts</option>
    <option>Computer Programmers</option>
</select>
```

my comment box code:-

```
<div class="biggest-container">
    <div id="mainContainer" class="mainContainer-one" class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="rounded bg-light p-3 static" class="position-static" id="cont">
            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM comment_table ORDER BY id DESC";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            ?>
                <div class="card mb-2 border-secondery" id="myTable">
                    <div class="card-header bg-secondary py-1 text-light">
                        <span id="fieldone" class="float-left font-bold fields">Field : <?= $row['field'] ?></span>
                        <span class="float-right font-bold">On : <?= $row['date_publish'] ?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body py-2">
                        <p class="card-text font-bold"> Posted By : <?= $row['name'] ?></p>
                        <p class="card-text font-bold"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt color-light"></i> Location : <?= $row['location'] ?></p>
                        <p class="card-text font-bold show-read-more"> Description : <?= $row['description'] ?></p>
                        <p class="card-text font-bold"> E-mail : <?= $row['email'] ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer py-2">
                        <div class="float-left">
                        </div>
                        <div class="float-right">
                            <a href="action.php?del=<?= $row['id'] ?>" class="text-danger mr-2" onclick="return confirm('Do you want to delete this comment?');" title="Delete"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
                            <a href="index.php?edit=<?= $row['id'] ?>" class="text-success" title="Edit"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please help me its very urgent please...you can send me the codes on "mohdaffan7806@gmail.com"

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the `<select>` the function should be triggered with `onchange="searchFun(this)"` instead of `onkeyup`, which is for keyboard events.

Then the function will be triggered when an option is selected.

the beginning of searchFun can then also be changed to:

```
<script>
        const searchFun = (select) => {
            var x = select.value();
```

This also looks strange:

```
        let field = <?= $row['field'] ?>
            var y = field.val();
```

Comment: Thank you bro but its not working any suggestions why its not working , please help me bro it seems that you are a very good programmer please help me

Answer (score 0):

What you have written here unfortunately doesn't make much sense. My general suggestion would be: try first writing this without the PHP, using only static HTML/JavaScript.

The biggest problem is the line

```
let field = <?= $row['field'] ?>
```

`$row` seems to be your loop variable in your HTML, how ever that JavaScript isn't inside the loop, so `$row` won't be defined (you should be getting an undefined variable error).

Moreover even if `$row['field']` were defined (let's say it contains the string `Example`), then that would generate the JavaScript line:

```
let field = Example
```

Which makes JavaScript interpret `Example` as a variable, which also wouldn't be defined.

Generally it's a bad idea to generate JavaScript with PHP. (There are cases where it makes sense, but this most likely isn't one.) I would suggest moving all JavaScript into a separate *.js file, so that you don't come into temptation to mix PHP and JavaScript.

Comment: can you please give me the codes it will help me a lot

Comment: please bro help me please tell me how to do this please bro